# How do you launch a second MainWindow.xib in an iPad application?

Tags: ipad, uibuilder

How do you launch a second MainWindow.xib in an iPad application?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a second MainWindow.xib?

Comment: Are you asking about the window for external video driven from the dock connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load the nib, most likely using NSBundle, and then call `makeKeyAndVisible` on the window in the nib. The best way to get the window is to use an outlet in the object loading the nib.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondWindow" owner:self options:nil];
[self.secondWindow makeKeyAndVisible]; //assuming the window was connected to a property named secondWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't.  Instead, you transition to the new top level modal view controller (either in a xib or programmatically created) that would have been in your second MainWindow.

Comment: ok, but what if I want a second MainWindow.xib?  (For example, to create a new View with a SplitViewController)?  Most feedback that this isn't something you want to do seems accurate, but how would I do it?  (Even if it is wrong.)